# Add multiple custom post type in URL

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-post-type

I've made a WordPress website people can rent cars from brokers. So I have 2 custom post types:

- broker
- car

There are about 10 different cars on the website. All these cars are for each broker exactly the same.

So I've created a page template page-brokers.php that lists all the brokers.
If you click on a broker, you go to the detail page of the broker single-broker.php

The URL is `saferental.be/broker/broker-name`

On the detail page of the broker, you'll see all the `10 different` cars. If you click on a car, you go to the car detail page, which is single-car.php

The URL is `saferental.be/car/car-name`

At the bottom of the car detail page, is a form to contact the broker you've selected previously. As you see in the URL, there is nothing mentioned of the selected broker.

When you select a broker, its information is saved in a session and pushed into hidden fields in the form.

Everything works perfectly:
- You select a broker
- You pick a car -> go to the car detail page
- Submit the car detail page form which sends the information to the selected broker.

The result I want to have:
- If you select a broker, you go to the detail page `saferental.be/broker/broker-name/` (this is already okay)
- If you select a car, you go to the car detail page which should be something like this: `saferental.be/broker/broker-name/car/car-name`

Test website:
http://safelease.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/

The brokers are at the bottom of the homepage.

Comment: Can the same car, be in different brokers?

Comment: you could use ACF and select the cars broker with a relationship field, and use permalink manager (supports ACF) to use that field in the url.

Comment: Yes, the same car can be in different broker. 
My newly created car "Volvo V40" is available for broker x, y and z. It's the same car.

Comment: You could create custom rewrite rules to handle the URL structure you want (`/broker/broker-name/car/car-name`); however, it might be easier for you to use plugin like [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) - and with this plugin, just [create a new redirect](https://redirection.me/support/create-redirects/) with these settings: a) "Source URL": `/broker/([^/]+)/car/([^/]+)` b) "Regex" checkbox: checked c) "When matched": [`Pass-through`](https://redirection.me/support/redirect-actions/) d) "Target URL": `/car/$2`

Comment: @SallyCJ I've installed the redirection plugin and added your settings. But when I go to the url /broker/broker-dennis/car/volkswagen-golf/ I'm automatically redirected to /car/volkswagen-golf/

Comment: You mean redirected and the URL in the browser's address bar got changed? If so, then you probably didn't set the "When matched" option to `Pass-through`. Double-check that option and let me know.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, that already works ! :-) I'm getting closer.
Still one issue. When you go to the page for example /broker/broker-dennis/ The ID for broker "broker-dennis" is saved in a session. But when I immediately go to /broker/broker-dennis/car/volkswagen/, that ID isn't saved in the session.

I retrieve the broker's ID with

`function broker_session_value() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'broker') {
        //session_start(['use_cookies' => 0]);
        $_SESSION['broker'] = $post->ID;
    }
}`

But on the car detail page, the post_type isn't broker.

Comment: Try changing the "Target URL" to `/car/$2?broker_id=$1` - i.e. pass the `broker-name` part as a query string to the target URL, and from the *template* that displays the `/car/{car name}` page, you can retrieve the query string value like so: `$broker_id = isset( $_GET['broker_id'] ) ? $_GET['broker_id'] : '';`

Comment: (Sorry I did not notice your comment was edited.) And in that case, change the `if` in the `broker_session_value()` so that it looks like so: `if ( $post->post_type == 'broker' ) { $_SESSION['broker'] = isset( $_GET['broker_id'] ) ? $_GET['broker_id'] : $post->ID; }`

Comment: `$_GET['broker_id']` is, however, the broker post slug.. but can be fixed - let me know if you need help with that. (i.e. sample code)

Comment: Okay, it feels like we're getting there :-) already thank you for your help !
I've changed the if statement to `if ( $post->post_type == 'broker' ) { 
        $_SESSION['broker'] = isset( $_GET['broker_id'] ) ? $_GET['broker_id'] : $post->ID; 
    }`

When I'm on th /car/{car-name} page, the $_SESSION['broker'] seems to be empty. Isn't that because of the if statement? Because you say post_type='broker' but on the car detail page the post_type = car

Comment: Ops sorry.. yes, you're right. I didn't include the `$post_type` check at first, but edited it and included it. Change the "Target URL" to `/car/$2?broker_name=$1` and then try [this](https://pastebin.com/Ris4zvUs). Let me know.

Comment: @SallyCJ Okay I've changed the "Target URL" to `/car/$2?broker_name=$1` and replaced the function broker_session_value() to your example. I've upload the site to a staging environment: http://safelease.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/ You can select the broker at the bottom of the homepage (there are 3 test brokers). If you select one, you got to the broker detail page. At the top of that page, you see the broker logo which means that the session is okay. But I you click through to the car detail page, you don't see the logo. Or if you use url /makelaar/{slug}/wagen/{slug}, the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183697/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-dennis-perremans).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep that car detail page also will available under `saferental.be/car/car-name`?

If not, so — just put car detail page as child page to broker and url for this page will be `saferental.be/broker/broker-name/car/car-name`

If you want to many different urls for the same page — try to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/mapping-multiple-urls-redirect-same-page/

Comment: Yes, the cars may only be available under /broker/broker-name/car/car-name
But how do you make a detail page a child? I know that you can make a "normal" page a child. But my child page is single-car.php ...

Comment: I've tried the plugin you've mentioned. But what RegularExpression do I have to use? I've tried: ^broker/car/ and then Select Type = Custom Post type (Car).
But /broker/broker-name/car/car-name isn't available yet.

Comment: I've contacted the developer of that plugin you've mentioned, but it's not possible. That plugin simply redirects pages.

Comment: In WordPress you can set parent to any page. Just in details page set parent page as specific broker.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this myself.

This would go in your functions file:

```
// Setup rewrite rules something like http://yourdomain.com/broker/my-broker/car/my-car
add_action( 'init', 'rewrites_init' );
function rewrites_init() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'broker/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/car/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$',
        'index.php?broker=$matches[1]&car=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}

// Add variables
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars', 0);
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'broker';
    $vars[] = 'car';
    return $vars;
}

// catch the request for this page
add_action('parse_request', 'parse_requests', 0);
function parse_requests() {
    global $wp, $wp_query;
    if(isset($wp->query_vars['broker']) && isset($wp->query_vars['car'])) {
        // find the car post
        $posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'car',
            'name' => $wp->query_vars['car'],
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ));
        if(!empty($posts) ) {
            // set the global query or set your own variable
            $wp_query = $posts;
            // set the broker variable to use in your template
            $broker = get_page_by_path( $wp->query_vars['broker'], OBJECT, 'broker' );
            // include your custom post type template
            if (include(locate_template('single-car.php', true))) {
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            // handle error
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header(404);
            locate_template('404.php', true);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your car template, you should be able to access the `$broker` post variable.

After you have setup your rewrite rules, you may need to go to Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and save to set the rewrites.

Hopefully this helps you.